# Firebase notification data not callback didReceiveRemoteNotification when app in background

Tags: php, ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send payload notifications from php to ios with some custom data, when the app is in background and received a notification then tab on that notification the app is open but it's not calling the **didReceiveRemoteNotification** function. it's work only if JSON has **data** only without the **notification** param.

**JSON that is sent from PHP to firebasr API**

```
{
   "to":"[Token]",
   "priority":"high",
   "content_available":true,
   "notification":{
        "title":"TITLE",
        "body":"Body",
        "sound":"default",
        "badge":"1"
    },"data":{
         "type":"link",
         "image":"",
         "link":"",
         "itemId":"",
         "categoryId":"",
         "groupId":""
    }
}
```

**ios Code**

```
func application(application: UIApplication,   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){
  print("vvvvvvvvvvvvv=%@", userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
     FIRApp.configure()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
}


func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? With the app in the background content_available set to true you should get the appDidReceiveRemoteNotification callback once when the message is received (and displays the notification) then again when the user taps on the notification. This is what I got when using your exact payload.

Comment: I'm using ios 9 , could you please show me example of your code Thanks

Comment: The FCM messaging sample is what I used, https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCM/AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing i found that "content available" should be inside the notification and it should be like this "content-available", the thing is that firebase re-structure the JSON in a way to make it readable for ios so you need to check how dose they send you the data in each test.

```
{
 "to":"[Token]",
 "priority":"high",
 "notification":{
    "title":"TITLE",
    "body":"Body",
    "sound":"default",
    "badge":"1",
    "content-available":true,
 },"data":{
      "type":"link",
      "image":"",
      "link":"",
      "itemId":"",
      "categoryId":"",
      "groupId":""
 }
}
```